# Windows 7 Shift-Right-Click Context Menus not Working Anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I've recently discovered that my Windows 7 Shift-Right-Click Context Menu in Explorer doesn't work any more. Whenever I try to Shift-Right-Click, nothing happens. This is on folders, files and the Taskbar. Normal Right-Clicks work fine. I thought it might a Shell Extension, so I uninstalled the only two custom shell extensions I have ([Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) and [Hash Check Shell Extension](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/)), but I still can't get the Shift-Right-Click Context Menus working. 
The problem is that I don't know when it stopped working, so I'm not sure if there was maybe a update or maybe a application I installed that caused this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured it out: turns out it wasn't a shell extension. It was the [How to Fake Back and Forward Buttons With a Three-button Mouse](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45191/how-to-fake-back-and-forward-buttons-with-a-three-button-mouse/) from How-To-Geek...